# NHibernate Lazy Loading Issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Here are steps that i am doing 
1) get all the entites to process the data
2) process each entity individually

```
ForEach Entity
   {       
     using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
             - Modify Entity
             - Modify Child objects //Childs can be accesed by Lazy loading
             - _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Update(Entity);
             - _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Flush(); 
             - scope.Complete();
     }
  }
```

So Once, process of one entity is done and started to process next entity at the time of Modify child objects throws lazy loading exception saying session got closed.

Can anyone please help me find the cause of this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: what is `repository` ? provide more code to make this question more clear

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to flush anything because you are already making a using statement, that will clear your object once it is out if scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first modification works I would guess that repository or scope as a side effect are closing the session.